# Theme changer inside application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I would like to create a buttons which after being clicked change background of my app in all other pages. ex. button black changes background to black. button blue changes background color to blue.
Any ideas? I couldn't find any tips for,actually,changing backgrounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main Grid (background) in any WP7 application is the Layout root. In your XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
</Grid>
```

To change the Background color, in the Button Click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }
```

You can change the background of any Grid using same format of the code.

Comment: it's ok, but does it change color of all backgrounds in all pages? one button for all backgrounds.

Comment: No. It changes the Background for the current Grid. If you wish to change the background color of all the pages, 
1) Store the Color value. 
2) Everytime a new page loads, change the color of the Background Grid to the stored Color Value. 
(The Color value can be stored as a Static value in the first page)

Comment: Ok, now I get it.
one more question. Can this static value be stored in isolated storage? Once changed is stored and restored after app resume or relaunch.